# CSS flexbox not working properly after linking Bootstrap 4 CDN

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using CSS flexbox to make the header of my page with **display:flex;**
Somehow, when I am linking Bootstrap 4 CDN link to my HTML, the flexbox doesn't behave like flexbox and different divs within flexbox come down to different lines.
Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help others achieving a better solution for your problem please share more information about your issue on your post, code snippets are the best way to give other supporters a clearer image of what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom `CSS` `class` is now conflict with **Bootstrap-4** `CSS` `class`. If you want to avoid this conflict you have to do following:

1. First add the **Bootstrap-4** `CDN` then your custom `CSS`. It will overwritten bootstrap `CSS` by custom `CSS`.

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your-custom.css" />
<!-- Your custom CSS -->
```

2. If above solution isn't fix your issue go to your html change bootstrap `class` to custom `class`.

**Example:**

```
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<!--  -->
```

Above class are reserved by bootstrap. If above `class` are conflict with your `.navbar` `class` please change that `class`.

```
<nav class="my-navbar"></nav>
<!-- OR -->
<nav class="navbar my-navbar"></nav>
```

3. If above solution not working then use `!important` after `CSS` property. It will overwritten bootstrap `CSS` by custom `CSS`.

**Example:**

```
.navbar{
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Note: Try to avoid `!important` `CSS` property. Use new `class` to overwrite bootstrap `CSS`.

Comment: I tried it after posting the question and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your css is overruled by the css of bootstrap. Since you are using CDN you can't change the bootstrap css.

I suggest you add '!important' to your header styles just to see if this will override BS css.

You can check to see which styles are used bij looking at your page in Chrome, press F12.
Select the 'Elements' tab. Select your header on the left side, and check the Styles on the right. It will show you which styles are used.